In F#, can "failwith" return a correct datatype from within an Async block?
The below code compiles correctly -- but looks terrible to me. The basic problem is that an async block of each type needs to be returned for use with StartChild. However, there are some conditions in which the intended "save" cannot be run due to insufficient information. But the only way I could make this work is to supply a meaningless record as an async.
There must be a better way.
I apologize for the formatting--it got messed up. (I am using Elmish.wpf as the the framework). As can be seen below I have had to create records like:
return! async { return {ComplexityId = -1} }

and
async { return {EncounterId = -1; Procedures = Seq.empty<ScheduledProcedure>}}                            

to allow correct compilation. Is there a better way?

let SaveReturnToOffice = async {
  let r =   match m.Encounter with
            |None -> failwith"Must have an encounter"
            |Some E -> match m with
                        |{RtoBy = Some "c"}  -> {Id = Guid.NewGuid(); RtoId = None; EncounterId =Some E.EncounterId; Rtoby= Some "c"; 
                                                  Rtoon = m.SelectedCalendarDate; Rtonum = None; Rtounit=None; OrderTime=None}                                                                                           
                                                
                        |{RtoBy = Some "i"}  -> {Id = Guid.NewGuid(); RtoId = None; EncounterId =Some E.EncounterId; OrderTime = None; Rtoby= Some "i";  
                                                  Rtoon=None; Rtonum = m.SelectedCount; Rtounit=RTO.timeunitbase m.SelectedTime }
                                               
                        |{RtoBy = Some "d"}  -> {Id = Guid.NewGuid(); RtoId = None; EncounterId =Some E.EncounterId; OrderTime = None; Rtoby= Some "d";  
                                                  Rtoon=None; Rtonum = None; Rtounit=None }
                                               
                        |{RtoBy = Some "p"}  -> {Id = Guid.NewGuid(); RtoId = None; EncounterId =Some E.EncounterId; OrderTime = None; Rtoby= Some "p";  
                                                  Rtoon=None; Rtonum = None; Rtounit=None}
    return! saveOrderAsync (None, None, Some r) 
}

let SaveComplexity = async {
 
   match m.Encounter, m.PatientType, m.Complexity with
    |Some E, Some P , Some C -> return! saveComplexityAsync ( E.EncounterId, P, C)
    |_, _,_-> return! async { return {ComplexityId = -1} }
}

let SaveScheduledProcedures = async {
    match m.Encounter with
    |Some E -> return! saveScheduledProceduresAsync (E.EncounterId, m.ScheduledProcedures)
    |None -> return! async { return {EncounterId = -1; Procedures = Seq.empty<ScheduledProcedure>}}                             

    }

let saveCheckOut () = async {
    // start all computations simultaneously. Each computation returns a different type, so use StartChild (not Parrallel)
    let! fn1 = Async.StartChild SaveReturnToOffice
    let! fn2 = Async.StartChild SaveComplexity
    let! fn3 = Async.StartChild SaveScheduledProcedures

    // retrieve results. (wait for results)
    let! result1 = fn1
    let! result2 = fn2
    let! result3 = fn3

    return ()
}

m, Cmd.OfAsync.either saveCheckOut () SaveCheckOutSuccess SaveError

Edit: Ugh...not enough sleep! As Brian suggested below, simply make the Async return <'t option>. i.e., Change |None to |None ->return None and the return! to let! h=... followed by return h |> Some.

All works better this way.



Can you just return a None value of Option<'t> instead of creating a dummy instance of your type 't? In the happy path, you'd then return Some { ... }, then check the return value with a match before proceeding.

you probably want to return failwith... ?

@BrianBerns I tried, I may have made a mistake, but I can't seem to return Async<'t option>. I probably don't have the syntax correct. If it can be done, that would be great!

@BrianBerns You are correct. (Sleep helps.) :)
